CodeIgniter Shield - Problem with email field in database
i trying to make simple user management and login system. From CodeIgniter shield documentation it seems possible to make email as optional parameter by do some config in Auth.php but it seems that not possible based on database structure configuration which from the setup migration config it set as unique and not nullable field. Is there any configuration i miss or the only way is make new migration to modify the field? Also, will this impact soft delete feature because the unique parameter in the email field?
I already try to checking each CodeIgniter Shield configuration file, but i didn't know if i missed anything.
